# How to convert image pixels into the same position in lat and lng for google maps use

Tags: javascript, google-maps, math, google-maps-api-3

The Google Maps API allows you to integrate your own map with the API, which i have done, but I have some code that places a marker on my original map, which has pixel positions.

What I wish to achieve is converting the pixel position form the original PNG map, into the relative position in (lat, lng) so that i may place markers on the new google maps chunks, but so far I've been unable to achieve this, has anyone done anything similar as I am looking for pointers on how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Read about map coordinates at 
   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#MapCoordinates
2. Convert your map to the base tile size (256x256) and translate your marker positions.
3. Convert your now translated marker positions to LatLng positions using the map projection: map.getProjection and projection.fromPointToLatLng.